# Загрузка методов фреймворка в программу

Tags: c#, .net

Возможно ли загрузить все используемые фреймворком библиотеки в программу, чтобы она запускалась на компьютерах без установленного фреймфорка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, с [.NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx) это возможно.

Но при этом не забудьте о текущих ограничениях:

- ваша программа должна быть скомпилирована не под .NET Framework, а под .NET Core
- вследствие этого десктопные приложения (WinForms, WPF) сразу отпадают
- целевая платформа вашей программы должна быть Windows 10
- вам всё же придётся таскать с собой dll-ку рантайм-библиотеки
- вам придётся кое-где указывать [метаданные вручную](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600165.aspx#Step6) (например, для классов, которые будут сериализироваться или с которыми будет использована рефлексия), и тестировать, не забыли ли вы что-нибудь

Со временем какие-то из этих ограничений уйдут. Но если вы новичок в .NET, я бы не советовал сейчас (2015 год) этим пользоваться.